# How to implement Friendly URL in Liferay portal

Tags: url, friendly-url, liferay

I have to simplify the URL. I am using liferay portal.

URL at present look like this:

http://10.11.201.144:8080/web/guest/marketing?p_p_id=EXT_6&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_EXT_6_pageName=aboutus

I need to simplify it like: http://10.11.201.144:8080/web/guest/marketing/aboutus
or some what easy.

Life ray provides Friendly URL option i don't know how to use it..
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but this parameter from the [Liferay documentation](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.2/official/liferay-administration-guide.pdf) (page 189, section "DEFAULT USER PRIVATE LAYOUTS") sounds nice:

```
default.user.private.layout.friendly.url=/home
```

There is also one for Guest users.

Answer (score 0):

The following documentation explains how to do this in a tutorial:
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/mvc/-/knowledge_base/6-2/making-urls-friendly

Comment: Links should never be the only piece of information in your answer.  Please see the [answer] page for how to write a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

I documented the steps for this 2 years ago on my blog just in case I need it again. Here you go: http://elshawwa.blogspot.com/2009/05/liferay-virtual-hosting-friendly-url.html

Comment: Links should never be the only piece of information in your answer.  Please see the [answer] page for how to write a good answer.