# Liferay cms url changes on content change

Tags: content-management-system, liferay, web-content

We've been trying to work with Liferay CMS to create **Web Content** (liferay terminology). The content is versioned in the sense, each time we change the content and publish it, the version increments.
This has an impact on the URL which is publicly exposed, and we're facing the trouble of changing the URL on content change.
Is there a way of getting a published URL that reflects change in content without changing the URL?

Comment: Can we get an example of the URL you are using to directly reference the web content?

Comment: Example URL: http://localhost:8081/c/journal/view_article_content?groupId=11314&articleId=11642&version=1.7
Wanted a URL which doesn't have version or which always gives the latest version of the content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use friendly urls in this case. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332993/how-to-implement-friendly-url-in-liferay-portal) for some more info.

Comment: Dirk, friendly URL can be configured for pages. But, we're trying to get URL for the published web content, which doesn't change on content change.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you are able to grab the latest journal content with any invokable URL because it requires a version number to be passed along with the request (otherwise it will just grab the first version not the last).

A work around would be to create a hook plugin that modifies the /journal/view_article_content action path with your custom implementation to return the latest article.

See Liferay's [Portal Hook Plugins](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/portal+hook+plugins) wiki page on how to create a hook.

Then see Mika's blog post on the [specifics of overwriting a struts path](http://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/overriding-and-adding-struts-actions-from-hook-plugins).

Good Luck!